# luxadm disp equivalent for Red Hat?

Tags: rhel, solaris, storage

Is there an equivalent to:

```
luxadm disp *disk*
```

for Red Hat? I need to check that all the device address to the SAN are ONLINE for a certain disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
systool -b scsi -v

Device = "1:0:0:2"
Device path = "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:06:00.1/host1/rport-1:0-0/target1:0:0/1:0:0:2"
delete              = <store method only>
device_blocked      = "0"
dh_state            = "detached"
iocounterbits       = "32"
iodone_cnt          = "0x6b8e2e"
ioerr_cnt           = "0x0"
iorequest_cnt       = "0x6b8e2e"
model               = "OPEN-V          "
queue_depth         = "32"
queue_type          = "none"
rescan              = <store method only>
rev                 = "6008"
scsi_level          = "4"
state               = "running"
timeout             = "60"
type                = "0"
uevent              = <store method only>
vendor              = "HP      "
```

does exatcly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

lsscsi, see: http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsscsi, may be what you're looking for.